# What is the max speed of an electrified wire in a strong magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

What I am thinking here is this. If a wire is moved inside a magnetic field an electric current is produced. Contrawise if a current is pushed through a wire floating in a magnetic field that wire will move. Do we know the acceleration applied to the wire? And is it the speed of electrons, the speed of light (but of course tiny thrust, and quite massive friction).

Comment: What is "it" in your last question referring to?

Comment: Surely you can reason to yourself that it is not the speed of light. Perhaps think of the old $F = ma$ thing we all learned once. The acceleration of the wire should depend on the mass of the wire, as well as the strength of the magnetic fields; one of which is produced by the current running through the wire. Thus it also depends on the strength of the current...

Comment: The thrust applied to the wire by the interaction between the magnetic and electric fields.

Comment: bleuofblue. No I can't. If I think of a photon sail then I think that each photon attempts to accelerate that sail to the speed of light. (Of course the photon is too little and and therefore has little thrust.) If I think of an electrified wire in a magnetic field I think the thrust should also be speed of light as the electric current 'reflects' off the magnetic field in the same way as the photon does off the sail.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration of a current-carrying wire of length $L$ carrying current $I$, with a magnetic field of strength $B$ oriented at an angle of $\theta$ to the wire experiences a force

$F=ILB\sin(\theta)$

which, according to $F=ma$ leads to

$a=\frac{ILB\sin(\theta)}{m}$.

I would also like to note that the force from the wire comes from the Lorentz force (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) acting on individual electrons in the wire, not from the current "reflecting off the magnetic field" or anything like that.

Comment: And as far as the max speed goes, the speed of light, I would imagine, is the ultimate limit, assuming infinite time and space to accelerate in. This would mean that this expression changes in the relativistic regime.